# Overriding the "for" keyword in Ruby. Is it possible?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, overriding

I search around and tried overriding the "for" keyword but I found nothing.
I am trying something like that:

```
def for("maybe_arguments_go_here")
  print "Hello from function for!"
end

for i in 1..3
  print "Hello from for"
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? How do you want to change the behavior of `for`?

Comment: I am just experimenting with the language's inner structure

Comment: There is a reason keywords are called keywords. But you could always get the Ruby source and redefine how `for` works, or call it something else, and then recompile Ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't override the keyword itself, but one thing you can do is say what `for` does for your own classes. `for` calls `each` internally, so the following trick will work:

```
class MyFor
  def initialize(iterable)
    @iterable = iterable
  end

  def each
    @iterable.each do |x|
      puts "hello from for!"
      yield x
    end
  end
end

# convenient constructor
module Kernel
  def my(x)
    MyFor.new(x)
  end
end

for i in my(1..3)
  puts "my for yielded #{x}"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that 'overriding' a keyword is an option at any language, you can override methods and operators(operators themselves are methods in modern languages) only, `for` is a keyword in Ruby. However you still can do things like the following:

```
def loop(range)
  range.each{|i| yield i}
end

loop 1..6 do |x|
  #do something with x
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give the method an explicit receiver it would work, but you would not be able to use the method without explicitly putting self before it.

This would work:

```
def self.for(arg)
  arg + 1
end

self.for(1)
=> 2
```

OR

```
 class Aa
   def c
    self.for(1)
   end

   def for(arg)
     arg + 1
   end
 end

 b = Aa.new
 b.for(4)
 => 5
```

BUT, I agree with khell and some of the comments above that redefining keywords is a massive no no, of course, if we're just experimenting and having fun, then go for it!